# How to extend App wake-up time in ios

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I am using Location manager to wake-up my app when didExitRegion/didEnterRegion method called.
App is waking-up but according to my test it will be awaken for 10 second.

I want to extend this awaken time to 1 min, Is it possible?
Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes It is possible.

You can extend the awaken time by using the beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: method of UIApplication class.

Comment: Does it extend to 1 min?

Comment: I am testing with Backgroundtask. Thanx

Comment: Thanx, Actually its changed, you can not extend it to 600(10 min) sec but 180(30) sec. But its working. Thanx +1.